# Plotting 4d-data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have points in 4 dimensions (lets call them, v,w,y,z) , which I would like to visualize.

My plan is to have two squares, (`v x w`, `y x z`), next to each other and then just plot each point twice.

Given two points (`[1, 1, 1, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2]`) I envision something like this:

[image: 1337 paint skillz]

Given a small set of points, I could use different colors to show which points on the left correspond to the right. With a large set of points, that would be futile. But perhaps heat maps would then be the best to visualize it?

Or is there some alternative established way to visualize data of higher dimensions within python/matplotlib?

Here's some sample data:

```
>>> resultsArray[:,:4]
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.00495236,  0.03919034,  0.00495287,  0.03919042],
       [ 0.00240293,  0.02667374,  0.00220419,  0.02693434],
       [ 0.0011231 ,  0.0191784 ,  0.00104353,  0.01928256],
       [ 0.00547274,  0.04187615,  0.00657255,  0.04043363],
       [ 0.00291993,  0.0286196 ,  0.00292006,  0.02861962],
       [ 0.00128136,  0.01975574,  0.00121107,  0.01984781],
       [ 0.00591335,  0.04531384,  0.00873814,  0.04160714],
       [ 0.00345499,  0.0310103 ,  0.00396032,  0.03034784],
       [ 0.00149387,  0.02056065,  0.0014939 ,  0.02056065],
       [ 0.00274306,  0.02667374,  0.00220419,  0.02659422],
       [ 0.00123893,  0.01948363,  0.00108284,  0.01952189],
       [ 0.00162006,  0.02379926,  0.00143157,  0.02389168],
       [ 0.00347023,  0.0286196 ,  0.00292006,  0.02806932]])
```

Comment: In your data, v is close to y and w is close to z, so you could do a 2D plot of line segments (v, w) to (y, z) .

Comment: You could create a 2d scatter plot and use `v, w` as `x, y` coordinates, the `y` value to color the points and `z` value to scale the size of the points

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about a 3-D scatter plot, which actually comes out to be 4-dimensional when the color scale is included?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

sp = ax.scatter(data[:,0],data[:,1],data[:,2], s=20, c=data[:,3])
plt.colorbar(sp)
```

You can customize the color scale and projection orientation as you like.