# python matplotlib - How to plot 3+1 dimension data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got an array of 4 dimensions. The first 3 dimension, `x, y, z` are categorical integer variables with value range [-3,3]. The combination of them are unique, i.e. no same `x, y, z` values in 2 rows. The last dimension `value`, is a continuous positive float variable. For example:

```
x    y    z    value
0    0    0    1.0
1    0    1    2.5
-1   1    -1   0.3
3    2    1    0.06
```

I'd like to visualise the array with matplotlib in python. The plot will be a 3D plot with `x, y, z` as axes, and each datapoint will be a sphere, the radius of the sphere will be `value`. I have only done this in Tableau previously. How can I do this with python?

P.S. In the case that `value` is not necessarily positive, I'd love to know how to use color as indicator of sign of `value` in addition to above question. Though I suppose an argument of `color=sign(value)` will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it out based on @tnknepp's answer in [Plotting 4d-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806254/plotting-4d-data)

The code is as simple as:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

sp = ax.scatter(x,y,z, s=value, c=color)
plt.colorbar(sp)
```

where `s` is the size of bubble and `c` is the color.